# Intecept touch on an ad view, present alert, go forward based on response

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've got an app which uses Google Mobile Ads SDK to display ads in a queue. I want to be able to detect when a user clicks on an ad (not just touches it while scrolling). If I detect that they've clicked, I'd like to be able to show an alert notifying the user that they will be navigating away from the app if they continue, giving them two options - one to continue and another to cancel. If they choose continue then I want to not interrupt the default action that happens when they click on the ad. If they choose to cancel, I want nothing to happen.

I've read through Apple's document: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9

and have tried overriding `hitTest:withEvent:` on a container view for the actual ad view. This allowed me to detect the touch but I can't tell if is an actual touch or just the user scrolling. Also, I can't synchronously stop the return of `hitTest` with an alert. The function finishes before the response comes back from the alert (which is expected).

I've also researched synthesizing touch events but it seems that is highly discouraged and maybe the only way to do it is using private APIs which I don't want to do.

I feel like I'm close here but still missing some pieces, assuming what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your problem you could just create a clear UIButton with no text on top of the view that contains the ads, that way you can intercept the touch without having to worry about scrolling. I think using the responder chain is the wrong way to go about it because you want an event that requires a response from the user to trigger between when you detect the touch and when you want the ad event to fire, so there is no way to pause that even and allow it to continue at a later time.

I'm not sure about the second part of your problem as I don't have much experience with Google Ads but I suspect they have closed off any methods which would allow you to procedurally fire off the ad event without user interaction as it would open the system up to abuse. That is just my suspicion tho and it may be wrong. If I am wrong then avenues worth exploring would be calling sendActionsForControlEvents on any buttons within the Google Ads framework if they are exposed. If they are not exposed they you may be able to recursively search through child views of the top level view you do have access to and check if they are of type UIButton. It's possible they don't even use UIButton so this may be a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem you're really trying to solve is preventing accidental taps on ads when a user is scrolling. Assuming you're using a `UIScrollView`, you can disable user interaction on the `GADBannerView` when the user is scrolling and enable user interaction once the user has stopped scrolling.

For example:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    banner.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    banner.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

You may have to experiment with different `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to see which ones work for you. Here's a complete list: [**UIScrollViewDelegate**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate).

Comment: I really like this idea and I hope it works. Yes, we are trying to prevent accidental clicks. iOS does a pretty good job of this on it's own but some people still manage to click unintentionally.